# Visual Studio 2012 random bug or fail by me

Tags: visual-studio-2012

### The problem

Yeah, so I am having quite annoying problem where to I have not been able to find any solution from Google. The problem comes up in both situations starting up a new project or opening up old working one, all I get is emptiness everywhere, see picture below.

### What i have already tried

I have tried reinstalling the whole program couple times and I have patched it.

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBL67.png

Comment: Try running it as Administrator. Is there any difference?

Comment: Yeah that did it thanks guys, kinda funny how much time i have wasted on such and newbie thing.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just don't have your **solution explorer** open and visual studio doesn't open any file by default.

The solution explorer shows you all of the files and folders in the current solution and let's you open them.

Open it using **View > Solution Explorer** or press **Strg + Alt + L**.

Answer (score 0):

The solution explorer may not show up by default. You can show it with:

- Application menu: `View > Solution Explorer`
- Shortcut: `Ctrl + Alt + L`